# Dictionary different output than the trial site version

Tags: r, quanteda

I try to use LIWC dictonary 2015 version in R.

A dummy text for text analysis:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc
```

I try this line:

```
library("LIWCalike")
library("quanteda")
 liwcalike(data_char_testphrases)
liwc2015dict <- dictionary(file = "~/Dropbox/QUANTESS/dictionaries/LIWC/LIWC2015_English_Flat.dic",
'                            format = "LIWC")
' inaugLIWCanalysis <- liwcalike(data_corpus_inaugural, liwc2015dict)
' inaugLIWCanalysis[1:6, 1:10]
```

I expected to have results like the following which are avaible as reproduced simple example in the [official site](http://www.liwc.net/tryonlineresults.php), of course I believe there are more variables of LIWC these are some examples

```
LIWC Dimension  Your
Data    Personal
Texts   Formal
Texts
Self-references (I, me, my) 5.18    11.4    4.2
Social words    2.59    9.5 8.0
Positive emotions   2.35    2.7 2.6
Negative emotions   1.18    2.6 1.6
Overall cognitive words 6.59    7.8 5.4
Articles (a, an, the)   8.71    5.0 7.2
Big words (> 6 letters) 20.24   13.1    19.6
```

But I receive this results:

```
output[, c(1:7, ncol(output)-2)]
#>    docname Segment WC WPS Sixltr   Dic LINGUISTIC PROCESSES.FUNCTION WORDS
#> 1    text1       1  8   3  37.50 37.50                               25.00
#> 2    text2       2  6   5  16.67 50.00                               50.00
#> 3    text3       3  4   2   0.00 25.00                                0.00
#> 4    text4       4 18  12  11.11 61.11                               22.22
#> 5    text5       5  4   1   0.00 25.00                                0.00
#> 6    text6       6  7   3  14.29 28.57                               14.29
#> 7    text7       7  7   3   0.00 42.86                               28.57
#> 8    text8       8  5   4   0.00 80.00                               60.00
#> 9    text9       9  9   2  11.11 11.11                               11.11
#> 10  text10      10  9   2  22.22 22.22                               22.22
#>    Apostro
#> 1        0
#> 2        0
#> 3        0
#> 4        0
#> 5        0
#> 6        0
#> 7        0
#> 8        0
#> 9        0
#> 10       0
```

How can I take the results as they are in the example trial site version of LIWC?

Comment: Without your full (verbatim) output, it's not possible to say 100%, but if you pasted in the command from the demo site, then the dictionary command would not have worked for you unless you have access to my hard disk, namely: `~/Dropbox/QUANTESS/dictionaries/LIWC/LIWC2015_English_Flat.dic`. You will need to substitute your own dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

See this page on how to get almost the same result as LIWC: https://koheiw.net/?p=573